# How to mark an issue as resolved on Bit Bucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I am working on this project and I was assigned to work on an issue. I have finished my work on the issue. How do I make it resolved? I don't see any button that does that or do I need to add something in the commit message?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the work flow drop down if it doen't appear directly on the issue. You can also resolve issues using commit messages it seems. Please refer https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-issues-automatically-when-users-push-code-221451126.html

Comment: I don't see a workflow dropdown. The person who assigned me to the issue said this: "attach link to PR which resolved this issue and mark it as resolved". How do I attach link to the PR?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by PR. But if you don't see Resolve button anywhere, probably you do not have permission to resolve issues

Comment: By PR I mean Pull Request. Yes, that could be probably the case.

Comment: You can just go and copy the url of the pull request which is merged and add is as a comment to the issue. Seems you can also resolve issues based on commit messages. Didn't know that earlier. Edited my answer to include that too. Hope it helps.